# How to split a data table based on a contained word in R

Tags: r, datatable, split

I have a data table and I want to split it in multiple data tables based on one variable, but the value of that one variable may differ a bit. To illustrate what I mean, here is an example. Let's have this data table:

```
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|      Variable1       | Variable2 | Variable3 |
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|     New York         |      1000 |      5000 |
|     New York - Bronx |       156 |     98498 |
|     New Jersey       |       198 |      4894 |
|     Detroit          |      1658 |     74984 |
|     New York Queens  |     16516 |    498465 |
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

And the output should look like this:

1st one

```
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|      Variable1       | Variable2 | Variable3 |
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|     New York         |      1000 |      5000 |
|     New York - Bronx |       156 |     98498 |
|     New York Queens  |     16516 |    498465 |
+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

2nd one

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| Variable1  | Variable2 | Variable3 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
| New Jersey |       198 |     4894  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

3rd one

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Variable1 | Variable2 | Variable3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Detroit   |      1658 |     74984 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to create a grouping variable for splitting the data.frame into a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
split(df1, sub("^(\\w+\\s+\\w+).*$", "\\1", df1$Variable1))
#$Detroit
#  Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
#4   Detroit      1658     74984

#$`New Jersey`
#   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
#3 New Jersey       198      4894

#$`New York`
#         Variable1 Variable2 Variable3
#1         New York       100      5000
#2 New York - Bronx       156     98498
#5  New York Queens     16516    498465
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Variable1 = c("New York", "New York - Bronx", 
"New Jersey", "Detroit", "New York Queens"), Variable2 = c(100L, 
156L, 198L, 1658L, 16516L), Variable3 = c(5000L, 98498L, 4894L, 
 74984L, 498465L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Just one more question. I guess "\\w+\\s+\\w+" means word, space, word. But what if there was also something like, let's say, "New York Something", which would be not desired to be grouped with other "New York" rows. Would I have to do it manually?

Comment: @PanMiroslav  May be you need to `filter` out that earlier, i.e. `subset(df1, !grepl('Something', df1$Variable1))` before `split`